# Delete Instance Variables from Objects in an Array

Tags: ruby

I'm new to Ruby and I'm just having a play around with ideas and what I would like to do is remove the @continent data from the country_array I have created.  Done a good number of searches and can find quite a bit of info on removing elements in their entirety but can't find how to specifically remove @continent data.  Please keep any answers fairly simple as I'm new, however any help much appreciated.

```
class World
  include Enumerable
  include Comparable

  attr_accessor :continent
  def <=> (sorted)
    @length = other.continent
  end

  def initialize(country, continent)
    @country = country
    @continent = continent
  end 
end

a = World.new("Spain", "Europe")
b = World.new("India", "Asia")
c = World.new("Argentina", "South America")
d = World.new("Japan", "Asia")

country_array = [a, b, c, d]

puts country_array.inspect

[#<World:0x100169148 @continent="Europe", @country="Spain">, 
#<World:0x1001690d0 @continent="Asia", @country="India">, 
#<World:0x100169058 @continent="South America", @country="Argentina">, 
#<World:0x100168fe0 @continent="Asia", @country="Japan">]
```

Comment: Why do you have an unused variable `sorted` in the definition of `<=>`?, and where fors `other` come from?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use `remove_instance_variable`. However, since it's a private method, you'll need to reopen your class and add a new method to do this:

```
class World
  def remove_country
    remove_instance_variable(:@country)
  end
end
```

Then you can do this:

```
country_array.each { |item| item.remove_country }
# => [#<World:0x7f5e41e07d00 @country="Spain">, 
      #<World:0x7f5e41e01450 @country="India">, 
      #<World:0x7f5e41df5100 @country="Argentina">, 
      #<World:0x7f5e41dedd10 @country="Japan">]
```

Comment: Thanks this is great and also ties in nicely with my current learning so much appreciation!

Comment: Removing instance variables is not something I like to do.  I'd hesitate to suggest this kind of thing to somebody that is fairly new to The Programming Life (at least not without a cautionary message about it).  What happens at later places in the code when we try to access `country_array[0].continent` if it's been removed?

Comment: @dustmachine I agree with your general sentiment, but note that with the class as it stands there is no `.continent` accessor method, so the same thing would happen as happens currently: `NoMethodError` :)

Comment: There's a `attr_accessor :continent` line, but maybe that was an edit after your comment.

Comment: You should be defensive and add a guard clause to check if the instance variable is defined. If you don't you will get an error "instance variable ... is not defined". 
`remove_instance_variable(:@country) if instance_variable_defined?(:@country)`

Answer (score 3):

The following example will set the `@continent` to `nil` for the first `World` object in your array:

```
country_array[0].continent = nil

irb(main):035:0> country_array[0]
=> #<World:0xb7dd5e84 @continent=nil, @country="Spain">
```

But it doesn't really *remove* the continent variable since it's part of your `World` object.

Have you worked much with object-oriented programming? Is your `World` example from a book or tutorial somewhere?  I would suggest some changes to how your `World` is structured.  A `World` could have an array of `Continent`'s, and each `Continent` could have an array of `Country`'s.

Names have meaning and variable names should reflect what they truly are. The `country_array` variable could be renamed to `world_array` since it is an array of `World` objects.

Comment: I am a beginner and following a book, although this is an attempt to play with some of the things I've learnt so far, thank you for the answer though.

Answer (score 1):

99% of the time I would recommend against removing an instance variable, because it's extra code for no extra benefit.

When you're writing code, generally you're trying to solve a real-world problem. With the instance variable, some questions to ask are:

- What real world concept am I trying to model with the various states the variable can be in?
- What am I going to do with the values stored in the variable?

If you're just trying to blank out the continent value stored in a `World` object, you can set `@continent` to `nil` as dustmachine says. This will work fine for the 99% of the cases. (Accessing a removed instance variable will just return `nil` anyway.)

The only possible case (I can think of) when removing the instance variable could be useful is when you're caching a value that may be `nil`. For example:

```
class Player
  def score(force_reload = false)
    if force_reload
      # purge cached value
      remove_instance_variable(:@score)
    end

    # Calling 'defined?' on an instance variable will return false if the variable
    # has never been set, or has been removed via force_reload.
    if not defined? @score
      # Set cached value.
      # Next time around, we'll just return the @score without recalculating.
      @score = get_score_via_expensive_calculation()
    end

    return @score
  end

  private
  def get_score_via_expensive_calculation
    if play_count.zero?
      return nil
    else
      # expensive calculation here
      return result
    end
  end
end
```

Since `nil` is a meaningful value for `@score`, we can't use `nil` to indicate that the value hasn't been cached yet. So we use the undefined state to tell us whether we need to recalculate the cached value. So there are 3 states for `@score`:

1. `nil` (means user has not played any games)
2. number (means user played at least once but did not accrue any points)
3. undefined (means we haven't fetched the calculated score for the Player object yet).

Now it's true that you could use another value that's not a number instead of the undefined state (a symbol like `:unset` for example), but this is just a contrived example to demonstrate the idea. There are cases when your variable may hold an object of unknown type.